# Can you use INSERT and IF in a SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to check if a value exists in table A and if it does I need to insert that value in a table B.

What is the best way to do this in SQL only?

Comment: `INSERT..SELECT..WHERE..`

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: @marc_s, With the details given, this is solvable in standard SQL, that will work on a number of RDBMSes.

Comment: I have 2 tables Classes and School. I need to check if the section field entered by the student exists the Class.Section column and if it does then I need to enter this section in the School.section column. I am using SQL 2008

Answer (score 4):

Use `INSERT...SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO Table_B SELECT Field FROM Table_A WHERE Condition
```

Comment: I have 2 tables Classes and School. I need to check if the section field entered by the student exists the Class.Section column and if it does then I need to enter this section in the School.section column. I am using SQL 2008

Comment: Please start trying to fix it yourself and post your code/update your question if you run into problems. We won't write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT into Table_B(ID_Number, DTL_1, DTL_2, DTL_3) 
SELECT ID_Number, DTL_1, DTL_2, DTL_3 
FROM Table_A 
LEFT JOIN Table_B 
   ON Table_A.ID_Number = Table_B.ID_Number 
WHERE (((Table_B.ID_Number) Is Null));"
```

In the above example, ID_Number is a KEY (or INDEX) field that will not ever contain duplicate entries.  You will need similar fields in your tables.

You're going to need the join, unlike the other responses, or you won't be able to determine if the record exists in one table but not the other.